# T-SQL create label “week #1: 1/1/18 - 1/7/18”

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, range, label

Is there a way to create a table with the following?

```
Label 
“week #1: 1/1/18 - 1/7/18”
“week #2: 1/8/18 - 1/15/18”
```

And so forth?

Basically, I’m looking for the week number and the date range that week includes.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for editing. Placed the question by mobile

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want as a starting point, is a "date dimension" or "calendar table". [Here's one](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) of many examples for creating them (creating them is not really the issue though, it's how you use them that's more important).

In your example, it looks like you want to pivot the data (create a crosstab). As a rule of thumb, you're generally better off pivoting on the client application, than you are persisting that denormalised anti-pattern in a relational database.

Here's a fictitious example:

```
  DECLARE @start_date as datetime = '20180301';
  DECLARE @end_date   as datetime = dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,GETDATE()),0);--midnight last night

   SELECT cal.week_starting   --The date of the start of the week eg 15 April 2018. 
          ,dateadd(d,6,cal.week_starting) as week_ending -- The date of the last day of the week eg 21 April 2018. You can cast as varchar, format and concatenate to the previous field to suit yourself.
          ,my_events.my_category
          ,count(*) as recs
     FROM my.CALENDAR cal
               JOIN dbo.big_list_of_events my_events ON cal.census_dttm = my_events.event_date
    WHERE my_events.event_date >= @start_date
          and my_events.event_date < @end_date
 GROUP BY cal.week_starting
          ,my_events.my_category
 ORDER BY cal.week_starting
          ,my_events.my_category
;
```

Once you get to this point you're ready to query it with your client application (eg Pivot Tables in Excel) and slice and dice to your heart's content. Again, you probably don't want data stored in your db as a crosstab.